# Validation summary not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why my validation summary not show after i click ligin button in my login control. It supposed to show an error message if i leave it blank in  username n password box right? Can you guys tell me what should i do? Im using a master page. Thank you.

```
   <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" 
                            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt">
                            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
                        </asp:Login>
                    </p>
                   <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
    ValidationGroup="Login1" />
```

Comment: Have you add the validation control to each textbox? Can you post the compete code

Comment: This code is working fine in my PC `</p>` is extra please remove that. Or this is the only code you write on your page? Or other code is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ValidationGroup="Login1"

must be specified on each validator & login button control.

Comment: @MinahSaja glad it helped ;) Damien.

Answer (score 0):

All your validation controls (LengthValidator, RegexValidator etc.) will need to be in the same `ValidationGroup` for the ValidationSummary to pick them up.  Can you confirm this is the case?