# RequiredFieldValidators on a custom composite control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, user-controls

I have designed a custom composite control. For simplicity's sake, let's say it looks like this:

```
Public Class MyCustomControl
    Inherits CompositeControl

Private _textbox As TextBox

Public Property Text As String
    Get
        EnsureChildControls()
        Return _textbox.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        EnsureChildControls()
        _textbox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
    _textbox = New TextBox() With {.ID = "textbox"}
    Controls.Add(_textbox)
End Sub
```

Now I am trying to allow consumers of `MyCustomControl` to use a `RequiredFieldValidator` to ensure that the inner `_textbox` is filled out when a form submits (on the client).

What I have tried:

- Added the `<ValidationProperty("Text")>` to the `MyCustomControl` Class and used `ControlToValidate="customControlID"` on the `RequiredFieldValidator` (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310082))
- Directly attach the validator via `ControlToValidate="customControlID:textbox"` as well as `ControlToValidate="customControlID_textbox"`
- Added an `IsRequired` attribute to `MyCustomControl` which adds it's own `RequiredFieldValidator` as a child control with `.ControlToValidate = _textbox.ID`

The third approach does appear to work (there are some javascript errors that I have not yet looked into) but I would really like to get the FIRST approach working (using the `ValidationProperty` attribute).

**TLDR: Is there any way to use the `ValidationProperty` attribute to achieve client-side validation on a custom composite control?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works (at least the simplified version running VS 2010) with the ValidationProperty attribute.  Make sure that you have defined the Text property of your RequiredFieldValidator so that a message actually displays when the field is not valid.

Edit Based on Comment About Validation Summary:

Confirm that your ValidationGroup property is set (and the same) for your RequiredFieldValidator, ValidationSummary, as well as the control that would fire the post back.

Comment: I am using a `ValidationSummary` to display the errors, along with the `ErrorMessage` property of the `RequiredFieldValidator`. When I submit the page, it goes through regardless of the value of the text box.

Comment: See this SO link, it may be your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677883/validation-summary-not-showing

Comment: The validation summary works fine if I use the same `RequiredFieldValidator` on a plain `input type="text"` box without the composite control.

Comment: The code you posted worked.  When I added the ValidationSummary it failed, but then when I added the ValidationGroup property to the CompositeControl, the ValidationSummary, and the button i made for testing, it worked again.